# Run Selenium Test from JSP Page

Tags: java, jsp, selenium

I want to create a JSP project which is possible to run Selenium test. I am not sure it is possible or not. Any one has any idea about this?

Comment: Obviously, . . . .

Comment: It works.. It does not matter if you use jsp or jsf or other technology to create HTML. Check out the documentation on how selenium works http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use selenium to test a page produced by a jsp just like any other web page.  Selenium can test web pages that are produced by any number of technologies on the back end.

For some background on jsps, keep in mind:  A jsp is converted by the web server to a servlet (it is converted to a java class that is a servlet) and then the servlet is compiled by the java compiler.  So a jsp is really just a servlet.

Comment: Hi Sean F. Thank for your comment, but it is not like this. I have a selenium app which is deployed on any server. Then when user want to run any tests, The selenium test should open any browser on client machine. But currently it start browser on server machine.

Comment: @mankeomorakort, Its okay if the browser starts in the server machine as long as it returns client the test result. Is it achievable?

Comment: @Bopsi, yes your are right, currently i have no choice to run browser on server.